# How to issue a warning if trying to reference a label in a starred equation environment?

Tags: equations, labels

My file is pretty big (it's over 100 equations and growing) and I don't want to check by hand which equation labels I've used. So my goal was to change all `equation` environments to `equation*`, but any reference to a labeled `equation*` outputs nothing or an "unrelated" number **without** creating any warning.

Is there a way to force such cases to produce a warning ?

MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*} \label{mylabel}
    \pi = 3.2
\end{equation*}
I want a warning if i'm trying to reference equation \eqref{mylabel} since the equation environment is starred.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It might be easier to solve your initial problem, and to check for each defined label whether it has been referenced. Depending on your OS, there are external solutions (like using regular expressions to extract all strings from `\label` and `\ref` commands and display those labels not `\ref`ed), or pure LaTeX solutions where each `\ref` command records its label and the `\label` commands check whether they have been used (the 'undefined label' check in reverse).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following causes `\label` calls from within `equation*` to print a warning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/equation*/begin}{%
  \renewcommand*{\label@in@display}[1]{%
    \errmessage{\string\label{#1} used in equation* environment!}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*} \label{mylabel}
    x = 3.2
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfectly what i was looking for. Thanks !

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear that!